# Replace phtml from register page magento2

Tags: magento2, module

I already enabled path hits in frontend view, but is not loading the "new phtml". What can i do?

edit:
magento Version is 2.1.6

My module files:
/company/CustomModule/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="customer_form_register">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" template="company_CustomModule::/form/register.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And the new phtml i changed a few things, but Does not load 
 the new file, inside /company/CustomModule/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

I need an assistance, thanks in advance.

i already try to run this commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean 
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

but not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the registration form in an Address Lines module and the commit can be found on GitHub

https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-Address-Lines/commit/1eb3a1d2888654e8ce2a50806dec4fea4049942e#diff-f5989e190f9922ccf827fe06050a362d

Comment: thanks. its works , i only change the name of referenceBlock and of argument